# Why is the C-Br bond considered polar?

Tags: bond, polarity

Why is a C-Br bond considered polar? From electronegativity considerations, both carbon and bromine have very similar electronegativities - 2.5 and 2.8 - respectively.

Nonetheless, I am told that such a bond would be polar. We generally classify bond between atoms with EN differences < 0.5 as non-polar; why would C-Br be an exception?

Comment: What is your source for this view? Who thinks this bond is polar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I poked around on the internet and found a lot of sites use the Pauling electronegativity scale ([link 1](http://periodictable.com/Properties/A/Electronegativity.al.html), [link 2](http://www.tutor-homework.com/Chemistry_Help/electronegativity_table/electronegativity.html)).  For carbon the value is 2.55 and for bromine 2.96.  Not quite a 0.5 difference, but closer - and this "rule" is somewhat arbitrary to begin with.  Also the dipole moment of bromobenzene is around 1.7 D ([link 3](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22998499)), certainly not insignificant.  I too would have said bromobenzene is polar.  It is not strongly polar, whether it is "a little" polar, "mildly" polar, "somewhat" polar, etc. seems to be the question - but that's just semantics.  Maybe the reason many people consider the $\ce{C-Br}$ bond to be polar is because it has a very observable effect on electrophilic aromatic substitution reaction rates.  Specifically, why should the relative rate for electrophilic aromatic substitution at the *meta* position in bromobenzene be slower that the rate in benzene itself unless you invoke the inductive effects caused by a polar $\ce{C-Br}$ bond?

Comment: I think that's what the person who made this claim had in mind, and it makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Would a C-Br bond show up on IR spectroscopy?

Comment: Yes, see  http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~bacher/General/30BL/IR/ir.html

Comment: Cool, does that also lend credence to the idea that the C-Br bond is polar?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think so.  A requirement for ir absorption is for a vibration to produce a net change in the *molecular* dipole moment.  Couldn't stretching a non-polar bond in a polar molecule produce a change in the molecular dipole moment?

Comment: What about looking at NMR shifts, @ron? Would that give us a hint at the polarity of a C-Br bond?

Comment: That is possible, particularly with 13C-NMR.  You'd need the right model compounds, but there is a substantial  shift of around 180-200 ppm per unit charge in 13C-NMR spectroscopy.

Comment: The only truly non-polar bonds are between the same elements in the same environment. Everything else is polar. In the $\ce{C-Br}$ bond already the different masses and the larger radii would induce polarity. Whoever proposed this rule made a very crude approximation. @Dissenter there is therefore no reason, why this bond should be IR inactive. It has a dipole moment to begin with, so every displacement of the atoms will induce a change of the dipole moment. The remaining question is only, how intense this signal will be compared to the other signals of a molecule.